# What is oracle database containers?

Tags: database, oracle

Please explain to me in accessible language what oracle containers and what they need.

```
CDB$ROOT
PDB$ROOT
PDBORCL
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/multitenant/overview/index.html  - Looks like it's part of their multitenant architecture

Comment: Please don't shovel this to another site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These containers are what Oracle describes as being their 'Cloud database' platform.

- CDB$ROOT is the root container where all instance information is kept
- PDB$ROOT is the container where the information of all pluggable databases is kept
- PRBORCL  is the default pluggable database, created on installation

For normal use, there is no need for pluggable databases. When you want to move things around quickly and easy, and high availability is demanded, pluggable databases come in handy.